# python string manipulation with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do some string manipulations with Pandas and I would deeply appreciate your help!
Here's my problem:
I loaded a list of words from a csv file into a pandas dataframe called df, so that it looks as follows (here, I created the df manually):

```
data = {'Keyword': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'Strawberry', 'Blueberry'], 'Kategory': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']}  

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now what I would like to do is some string manipulation based on the following conditions shown below. The output of the string manipulation should be saved to a new column.

```
# new column to store the results
output = []

# set up the conditions
for Keyword in df:
    if df[Kategory] == 'A':
        output.append(Keyword + 'first choice')
        print(Keyword + 'first choice')
    else:
        output.append(Keyword + 'second choice')        
        print(Keyword + 'second choice')
```

Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {'Keyword': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'Strawberry', 'Blueberry'], 'Kategory': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']}  

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
output = []
for idx, rows in df.iterrows():
    if rows['Kategory'] == 'A':
        output.append(rows['Keyword'] + " "+'first choice')
        # print(Keyword + 'first choice')
    else:
        output.append(rows['Keyword']+ " "+ 'second choice')        
        # print(Keyword + 'second choice') 

df['output'] = output
print(df)

Keyword Kategory                    output
0       Apple        A        Apple first choice
1      Banana        A       Banana first choice
2       Peach        A        Peach first choice
3  Strawberry        B  Strawberry second choice
4   Blueberry        B   Blueberry second choice
```

I have tried to replicate your approach , but you can use np.where , to iterate on a dataframe you have to use index and rows

Answer (score 2):

You can try `np.where`

```py
df['col'] = np.where(df['Kategory'].eq('A'), df['Keyword'].add(' first choice'), df['Keyword'].add(' second choice'))
```

```
print(df)

      Keyword Kategory                       col
0       Apple        A        Apple first choice
1      Banana        A       Banana first choice
2       Peach        A        Peach first choice
3  Strawberry        B  Strawberry second choice
4   Blueberry        B   Blueberry second choice
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine your error would be something like `key error: Kategory` `Kategory does not exist`. This is because the variable Kategory doesn't actually exist. When accessing keys in dictionaries, you must treat them as strings not variables.

Like this:

```
# new column to store the results
output = []

# set up the conditions
for Keyword in df:
    if df["Kategory"] == 'A':
        output.append(Keyword + 'first choice')
        print(Keyword + 'first choice')
    else:
        output.append(Keyword + 'second choice')        
        print(Keyword + 'second choice')
```

Good luck.